# Uniform distribution on natural numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and a random variable $Y$ which uniformly distributed on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$

Now I have to calculate the expected value of Y

$$\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]=\frac{1+\ldots+n}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^n n\right)$$

And the variance is given by

$Var(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2$

$$Var(Y)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^n n^2\right)-\left(\frac{1}{n}\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^n n\right)\right)^2$$

And the standard deviation is given by $\sigma=\sqrt{Var(Y)}$

$$\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^n n^2\right)-\left(\frac{1}{n}\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^n n\right)\right)^2}$$

Will be this the correct approach for this task

Comment: If you ask a question it would be kind to give a reply to the given answers. We delight to help, but we also like to get a reaction to our answers. Check also your previous questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are not quite correct. The argument has to depend on the index $i$.

$$\mathbb E(Y)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n i =\frac1n \cdot (1+2+\ldots+n-1+n)=\frac1n \cdot\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n+1}{2}\quad \color{blue}{\checkmark}$$

While your notation results in

$$\mathbb E(Y)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n n =\frac1n\cdot n\cdot  \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n 1}_{=n}=n \quad \color{red}{\texttt{X}}$$

Thus the variance is $$Var(Y)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i^2\right)-\left(\frac{1}{n}\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)\right)^2$$

$$Var(Y)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot   \frac{n\cdot (n+1)\cdot (2n+1)}{6}-\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}$$

Simplify it to obtain $\frac{n^2-1}{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

You should get 
$$E(X) = \frac{n+1}{2}$$
$$V(X) = \frac{n^2-1}{12}$$